# How to do meta-regression in SPSS?

Tags: spss, meta-analysis, sample-size, meta-regression

I am trying to manage a meta-regression in SPSS17 using the effect size as the dependent variable. I want to explore if my independent variables affects the effect size. Some small practical questions:

1. What is the minimum number of studies necessary for a meta-regression?

   - Some people suggest at least 10 studies are required. Why not 20 or 5 studies?
   - Is the total sample size an important consideration?
   - Why would 10 studies with 200 patients be enough, but 5 studies with 400 patients not be enough?
2. Can I enter all three regressors at once and report the global model, or do I have to enter one regressor at a time and report 3 models each one separately?

   - How does the correlation between the independent variables affects this choice?
   - How does the number of the studies affect the number of independent variables that I   should enter simultaneously?
3. Does the independent variable have to be a scale variable?

   - The dependent variable (=effect size) is, of course, scale. The independent variable must be also scale, or could be ordinal or nominal?
4. How can I weight my effect size for sample size?
5. What is the preferable level of significance?

   - Is p<0.05 still acceptable for clinical research in such an analysis?

Comment: Your topic is interesting, but you ask so many questions about different aspects of modeling and meta-analysis, and the questions are so much of a judgment-oriented rather than a how-to nature, that I'm afraid you're not going to get them answered satisfactorily in this venue.  If you could narrow down....

Comment: @rolando2 I agree, but the topic is hot. Also there is no meta-regression tag available. I hope that someone would spend time to add a paragraph for reference!

Comment: I modified your list of tags, hope you agree. Before I start answering your questions, I'd like to know how many data points you have.

Comment: @Bernd Twenty included studies, three independent variables, let's say 60 data points more or less, for the meta-regression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the built-in routines of SPSS to conduct a meta-regression (wrong standard errors; does not give you correct model indices; no heterogeneity statistics). Have a look at David Wilson's SPSS ["macros for performing meta-analytic analyses](http://mason.gmu.edu/~dwilsonb/ma.html)". One of these macros is called `MetaReg` which can perform fixed-effect or mixed-effects meta-regression. I would always use [Stata](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/stat/meta.html) or R. By the way, user [Wolfgang](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1934/wolfgang) is the author of an R package called [metafor](http://www.metafor-project.org/). This is an excellent piece of software to conduct meta-regression.

As a general (non-technical) intro to meta-regression, I can recommend Thompson/Higgins (2002) ["How should meta-regression analyses be undertaken and interpreted?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12111920)".

Now to your question:

*Q1: What is the minimum number of studies necessary for a meta-regression? Some people suggest at least 10 studies are required. Why not 20 or 5 studies?*

The answer can be found in [Borenstein et al (2009: 188)](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470057246.html):

> "As is true in primary studies, where
>   we need an appropriately large ratio
>   of subjects to covariates in order for
>   the analysis be to meaningful, in
>   meta-analysis we need an appropriately
>   large ratio of studies to covariates.
>   Therefore, the use of metaregression,
>   especially with multiple covariates,
>   is not a recommended option when the
>   number of studies is small. In primary
>   studies some have recommended a ratio
>   of at least ten subjects for each
>   covariate, which would correspond to
>   ten studies for each covariate in
>   meta-regression. In fact, though,
>   there are no hard and fast rules in
>   either case."

*Q2: Is the total sample size an important consideration?*

What is total sample size? The number of studies? Yes, it is important. Or the number of individuals? No, it is not (or less) important.

*Q3: Why would 10 studies with 200 patients be enough, but 5 studies with 400 patients not be enough?*

It is just a(n ordinary) regression. You wouldn't run a regression with 5 data points, would you? In your comment, you state that you have 20 studies which is enough to run a meta-regression.

*Q4: Can I enter all three regressors at once and report the global model, or do I have to enter one regressor at a time and report 3 models each one separately?*

It is just a regression. I would start with three simple bivariate models then build more complex models (be aware of multicollinearity, see below).

*Q5: How does the correlation between the independent variables affects this choice?*

A high correlation between your predictor variables will have a (negative) impact on your results. You should avoid that. Please consult a textbook for the problem of [multicollinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity).

*Q6: How does the number of the studies affect the number of independent variables that I should enter simultaneously?*

See the Borenstein et al citation.

*Q7: Does the independent variable have to be a scale variable? [...] The independent variable must be also scale, or could be ordinal or nominal?*

What is a "scale variable"? Do you mean a continuous/metric variable? You predictor variables can have any [level of measurement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement). However, if you have a categorical (nominal) predictor variable, you will have to deal with dummy variables (see [Multiple Regression with Categorical Variables](http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/multibook/mlt08m.html)).

*Q8: How can I weight my effect size for sample size?*

As far as I know, all meta-regression approaches expect the weights to be the inverse study variance, i.e. $\frac{1}{v_i}=\frac{1}{SE_i^2}$. Again, you will need standard errors :-)

*Q9: What is the preferable level of significance? Is p<0.05 still acceptable for clinical research in such an analysis?*

I cannot answer your question. That really depends on your research question. In my (non-clinical) research I am happy with p < 0.10.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer and references. I installed R to try metafor. More difficult than I was expected. There are many tutorials available but none for non-statisticians :-)

Comment: @ Staty Despair: You might be interested in [Yet another short introduction to R with some emphasis on meta-analysis](https://github.com/berndweiss/r_meta-analysis_intro/raw/master/report/p_introToR.pdf).

Comment: great job, undoubtendly! I don't know why I didn't find this text last days I searched hundrends of R related pages. Nevertheless, i still can't manage a simple meta-analysis using R, ...despite the fact that I already know the results from Cochrane RevMan. The missing piece of the puzzle, is a simple example of a real-life meta-analysis problem, solved by keeping the R syntax as simple/realistic as possible. "One word of truth outweighs the whole world" (Alexander Solzhenitsyn, 1970, Nobel lecture).

Comment: @BerndWeiss Just a note that as of now, the repository for that link no longer exists. I've done a quick search for it, but haven't been able to find it. In the meantime, there's another tutorial [here](http://www.edii.uclm.es/~useR-2013/Tutorials/kovalchik/kovalchik_meta_tutorial.pdf) for meta-analysis in R.

Answer (score 2):

These are some wonderful responses to your initial questions, and the reference guide is particularly helpful.

If you're looking for a relatively simple package to do meta-regression, may I recommend Borenstein 's software package [Comprehensive Meta Analysis](http://meta-analysis.com). It is limited to meta-regression of a single predictor but this can be scale/continuous or it can be categorical. The output and graphics produced are easy to follow, and unless you're using multiple predictors it will suffice. Given that you're talking about a small study size (eg 10) you probably wouldn't be able to detect multiple predictors anyway.